# ATmega 32A and 2560 R3 register to pin mapping?

Tags: arduino-mega, pins, atmega2560

I've been doing research for the last few hours trying to determine the mapping of physical pins to memory-mapped I/O registers for the Arduino Mega board (which is an ATmega 2560 R3).

- [My code is on GitHub](https://github.com/naftulikay/vw-cdc-emulator/pull/2) in a pull request, but hasn't been merged yet because I'm not finished yet.
- [This](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/ddad3abe90310da2d4769531a92f0dcc#file-vag_cdc-c) is the upstream example [I'm working from](http://schuett.io/2013/09/avr-raspberry-pi-vw-beta-vag-cdc-faker/), which was written for an ATmega 32A.
- [Here is Arduino's 2560 pin mapping](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560) which doesn't tell which registers are mapped to which pins.
- [Here is `avr/iomxx0_1.h`](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/9e881057b9c1b389ca7dc4a0dcbed76a) which defines the ports with simple numbers that I can't make heads or tails of.
- [Here is a collection of links](https://github.com/naftulikay/vw-cdc-emulator/wiki/Arduino-Mega-2560-R3-Documentation) relevant to my research.
- I [broke down and cross-referenced](https://github.com/naftulikay/vw-cdc-emulator/wiki/Upstream-Example) all of the uses of memory-mapped I/O registers in the upstream example.

Some of the registers used include `CS11`, `DDB4`, `DDRA`, `DDRB`, `GICR`, `INT0`, `INT1`, `ISC00`, `ISC10`, `MCUCR`, `PA0`, `PB5`, `PB7`, `PD2`, `PD3`, `PIND`, `PORTA`, `PORTD`, `SPCR`, `SPDR`, `SPIF`, `SPSR`, `TCCR1B`, and `TCNT1`. I can't figure out which pins these are and/or what they do.

Here is a diagram provided by the upstream example:

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not very good at reading these diagrams so I'm doing my best.

How can I determine the mapping of these registers to physical ports on both the ATmega 32A, which is the board the example was originally written for, and the ATmega 2560 R3, which is the board I'm currently working with?

Comment: Here is an alternative GPIO mapping: https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-GPIO/blob/master/src/Hardware/AVR/Board.h#L225, Please note the Register and Pin bit mapping, names, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What is ATmega2560 R3? There is ATmega2560 MCU or Arduino Mega R3. do you want the mapping of pins of Arduino Mega or the pins of the ATmega2560 MCU.

The mapping of pins of the ATmega 2560 chip is in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf).

The mapping of the Arduino Mega pins to ATmega2560 pins and registers is in [the schema of the board](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/MEGA2560_Rev3e_sch.pdf) or in the Arduino AVR boards package variants [mega folder](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/variants/mega/pins_arduino.h).

The link "Arduino's 2560 pin mapping" in your question shows the mapping too. Registers are PA, PB,... and every register covers to 8 pins with the 8 bits of the register. For example PB3 is pin 50 of the board.

Comment: [This](https://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-mega-2560-r3-board-atmega2560-atmega16u2-usb-cable/) is the exact board that I bought, and I'm looking for a reference on which pins on the board correspond with which registers exposed in the `avr` C library. The schema doesn't seem to list things like `PORTA` and so on that are referenced in the code I'm working from.

Comment: it is an Arduino Mega clone. the link to schema is in answer.

Comment: Because I'm porting code that I did not write. I need to understand what the code is actually doing before I can start porting it to my board.

Comment: but the schema clearly shows the register to board pin mapping. and that is what you asked. and the link "Arduino's 2560 pin mapping" in your question shows it too

Comment: I added something to the answer

Comment: @NaftuliKay, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Atmega32A is a 44 pin TQFP part with 4 8-bit IO ports.
It is kind of a crippled Atmega1284P. You may have an easier time just switching to a 1284P chip (also 44 pin TQFP) to take advantage of its 16K byte SRAM and 128K byte flash. There's an easy to use add-in to the Arduino IDE to use it.
https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore
I do a lot of 1284P designs and use it all the time.

Atmega2560 is 100 pin TQFP part with 10 8-bit and one 6-bit IO ports.

As your schematic only uses a few IO pins, the electrical connections will be simple - SPI for bootloading or downloading code
- 2 pins for serial
- 2 pins for other IO

If you look at the Arduino Mega2560 schematic, you can pick those out pretty readily.  The rest you will have to tweak up in your code.

Comment: he has a Mega. nothing special

Comment: I'm hoping to start with the board that I have (mega 2550) and then use conditional compilation to support other boards. I'm having a hard time with the schematic, as it doesn't seem to list which registers map to which pins, e.g. what is `PORTA` and what is it mapped to in `avr`'s C library and what does it do? Is there a reference I can look at to determine this?

Comment: The IDE already does that mapping. For example, on  '328P board, Port D is D7-D0, PORT B is D13 to D8 (upper two bits not used as IO), Port C 9 is D19 to D14. (upper two bit not used as IO).  Used to be that you could look at pins_arduino.h (I think that's the name) in the IDE folders for a particular board and read the mapping from PINx/PORTx to the IO pins.  I can't access arduino.cc from here to provide links to the specific boards, and I don't have them on this computer.